# Pip install Numpy Errors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

I tried to upgrade pandas from `19.2` to `20.2`

I did `pip -install --upgrade pandas`
and it ran successfully. However, now when I try to `import pandas` I get:

```
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I uninstall and re-install numpy with `pip uninstall numpy` and `pip install numpy`. But it seems like numpy is using a cashed version. I did install [numpy MKL a while back....](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy):

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.13.0-cp36-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.0
```

How do i install the "normal" version of `numpy`? As I believe this cached version is causing the issues

Comment: try upgrading, **pip install --upgrade numpy**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this link and download the relevant numpy .whl file:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Then navigate to the directory from which it is downloaded to and run the pip install command for that file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't mean to delete this answer. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use anaconda ? Try to run this script in cmd :

```
"conda install numpy"
```

Another solution might be to delete .pyc file your python project created. Python interpreter compiles source to byte code, which is stored in .pyc and byte code is afterwars executed by Pythons virtual machine.

Comment: I don't use anaconda. but I also looked for the .pyc files as in other posts. Couldn't find any. Any idea where some might be hiding?

Comment: solved the solution using the other poster's answer. But he deleted.

Comment: For python 2.7 - next to .py file, for python 3 - in  __pycache__ directory. more info https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#pep-3147-pyc-repository-directories